# Conditional PDF of multivariate normal distributions

Tags: matrices, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose that **Y**~$N\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. How can I find the conditional PDF of $Y_1$ given that $Y_1+Y_2=3$??  I am given a hint to firstly obtain the joint density of $Y_1$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ and then use the property of the conditional pdf that $f(x|z)=f(x,z)/f(z)$.

So far, I have tried to find the joint density of $Y_1$ and $Y_1+Y_2$. so I concluded to 
$\begin{pmatrix}
  Y_{1} \\
  Y_{1}+Y_{2}  
 \end{pmatrix}
$~$N
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0\\ 0 & 6\end{pmatrix}$
 but I feel that this is not correct.

Any help would be appreicated!!

Comment: Hint: If $Y$ is $N(M,\Sigma)$ and $Z=AY$ then $Z$ is $N(AM,A\Sigma A^*)$.

Comment: Yes but here I don't use $AY$ (multiplication). I am confused.

Comment: Yes you are: $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: okay I found the joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_1+Y_2$. After that, do I just divide the matrices by 3? @Did

Comment: @Did Okay I found $N(AM, A\sum A*)$. Is that the conditional pdf of $Y_1$? Where tdo I have to use the property $Y_1+Y_2=3$ ?? Is it correct to divide AM by 3 and $A \sum A*$ by 6?

Comment: Your joint distribution for $Y_1$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ doesn't look right. The variance of $Y_1$ has changed compared to the original given distribution.